# How to drill down into this JSON object within object

Tags: javascript, json

I am quite new to working with JSON objects.

I am trying to drill down to the property `value: Key Account Manager` in my JSON object

I think it will be something like:

```
${ JSON.parse(post.localization).values['locale'] }
```

JSON object:

```
[
    {
    jobId: 57,
    applyUrl: {
    localization: [
    {
    locale: "en-GB",
    value: "https://ohly-v2....."
    },
    {
    locale: "de-DE",
    value: "https://ohly-v2...."
    }
    ]
    },
    adUrl: {
    localization: [
    {
    locale: "en-GB",
    value: "https://ohly-v2...."
    },
    {
    locale: "de-DE",
    value: "https://ohly-v2...."
    }
    ]
    },
    timeZone: "Europe/Copenhagen",
    mediaId: "cf7b7c03-83fa-499a-95aa-f73a0641e8ae",
    advertisements: [
    {
    default: true,
    title: {
    localization: [
    {
    locale: "de-DE",
    value: "Key Account Manager"
    },
    {
    locale: "en-GB",
    value: "Key Account Manager"
    }
    ]
    },
    content: {
    localization: [
    {
    locale: "de-DE",
    value: "dfhsehrwe5hwejhwrtws"
    }
    }
]
```

Is their a website where I can copy and paste my data structure in and it will aid in drilling down to bits I need?

Comment: console.log the data and Press F12 in a recent browser - this assumes your object is valid JSON. What you posted isn't

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Try https://jsonbeautifier.org/

Comment: Also click `[<>]` snippet editor, past and click TIDY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Paste into http://json.parser.online.fr/ and fix the errors, In your case missing quotes and end brackets
2. Paste the fixed object into the `[<>]` snippet editor here and click TIDY
3. Scan the resulting data from left to right

```
jsObject[0]
  .advertisements[0]
    .title
      .localization
        .forEach(loc => console.log(loc.locale,loc.value))
```

The last Key Account Manager:

```
jsObject[0].advertisements[0].title.localization[1].value
```

---

```js
var jsObject = [{
  "jobId": 57,
  "applyUrl": {
    "localization": [{
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "value": "https://ohly-v2....."
      },
      {
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "value": "https://ohly-v2...."
      }
    ]
  },
  "adUrl": {
    "localization": [{
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "value": "https://ohly-v2...."
      },
      {
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "value": "https://ohly-v2...."
      }
    ]
  },
  "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
  "mediaId": "cf7b7c03-83fa-499a-95aa-f73a0641e8ae",
  "advertisements": [{
    "default": true,
    "title": {
      "localization": [{
          "locale": "de-DE",
          "value": "Key Account Manager"
        },
        {
          "locale": "en-GB",
          "value": "Key Account Manager"
        }
      ]
    },
    "content": {
      "localization": [{
        "locale": "de-DE",
        "value": "dfhsehrwe5hwejhwrtws"
      }]
    }
  }]
}]

jsObject[0].advertisements[0].title.localization.forEach(loc => console.log(loc.locale,loc.value))

// just the last
console.log(jsObject[0].advertisements[0].title.localization[1].value)
```

Comment: Instead of foreach how could I access just the last value? @mplungjan

Comment: `jsObject[0].advertisements[0].title.localization[1].value`

Comment: I fully understand now how to drill down into these objects thank you so much :)